# Javascript: Switch between 2 functions with 1 Click-Listener

Tags: javascript, function, menu, toggle, sidebar

I have a problem in that I want to code a Side bar with this cool animated Burger-Menu-Button("navicon1"). A cool animation effect for the Menu-Button is used the "open" class. I want to toggle the functions "openNav" and "closeNav" too if I click the menu button.

So this is what I want:

- If I click the Menu Button(navicon1) the first Time -> Menu-Button
  changes to X (this works) and executing javascript function "openNav"
- If I click the Menu Button(navicon1) the second Time -> Menu Button
  changes to normal (this works) and executing javascript function
  "closeNav"

Here is my code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#navicon1,#navicon2,#navicon3,#navicon4').click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('open');

        });
    });
    /* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px and the left margin of the page content to 250px and add a black background color to body */
    function openNav() {

        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "75%";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "75%";
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";

        }

        /* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0, and the background color of body to white */
    function closeNav() {

        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        check = 0;
        }
```

You can ignore navicon2-3, they are only for the css...

Thank you for your Help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable to remember the state:

```
var navOpen = false;
$("#navicon1").click(function() {
    if (navOpen) {
        closeNav();
        navOpen = false;
    } else {
        openNav();
        navOpen = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Worked perfektly Thank you! :)

Comment: @DreLoo Remember to mark the answer as answered if it answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating one function that handles the `toggleClass()` and call your other functions from there based on the state.

```
$('#navicon1').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');

    //if hasClass() then call function to open it

    //else call function to close it

});
```

Comment: He only wants to toggle the navbar when you click on `navicon1`, not all the other navicons.